# Installed prometheus-community / helm-charts but I can't get metrics on "default" namespace

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I recently learned about `helm` and how easy it is to deploy the whole `prometheus` stack for monitoring a Kubernetes cluster, so I decided to try it out on a staging cluster at my work.

I started by creating a dedicates namespace on the cluster for monitoring with:

```sh
kubectl create namespace monitoring
```

Then, with `helm`, I added the [prometheus-community repo](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack) with:

```sh
helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
```

Next, I installed the chart with a `prometheus` release name:

```sh
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -n monitoring
```

At this time I didn't pass any custom configuration because I'm still trying it out.

After the install is finished, it all looks good. I can access the prometheus dashboard with:

```sh
kubectl port-forward prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-0 9090 -n monitoring
```

There, I see a bunch of pre-defined alerts and rules that are monitoring but the problem is that I don't quite understand how to create new rules to check the pods in the `default` namespace, where I actually have my services deployed.

I am looking at `http://localhost:9090/graph` to play around with the queries and I can't seem to use any that will give me metrics on my pods in the `default` namespace.

I am a bit overwhelmed with the amount of information so I would like to know what did I miss or what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The Prometheus Operator includes several Custom Resource Definitions (CRDs) including `ServiceMonitor` (and `PodMonitor`). `ServiceMonitor`'s are used to define services to the Operator to be monitored.

I'm familiar with the Operator although not the Helm deployment but I suspect you'll want to create `ServiceMonitors` to generate metrics for your apps in any (including `default`) namespace.

See: https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator#customresourcedefinitions

Answer (score 1):

`ServiceMonitors` and `PodMonitors` are CRDs for Prometheus Operator. When working directly with Prometheus helm chart (without operator), you need have to configure your targets directly in `values.yaml` by  editing the `scrape_configs` section.

It is more complex to do it, so take a deep breath and start by reading this: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config